# Interactive Coin Puzzle

Tags: mathematics, coins

We see the standard version of the puzzle in: 
 [The Puzzle That's HARDER
 After Seeing the
 Solution!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHMm72vqAd8)

Which corresponds to the case $n=2$ in my follow up problem.

> ### 5 coin puzzle
>
> In short, you are presented with 2 types of coins (let there be small
>   ones and big ones since we all are not using the same currencies),
>   which are laid out in a straight line like: $\text{OoOoO}$
>
> Your goal is to reach the sorted state of coins: $\text{OOOoo}$
>
> By respecting the Rules:
>
> - You may only move 2 conjoined coins that are not of the same type per move.
> - The held coins cannot be twisted, separated or used to push other coins around.
> - All coins need to be aligned on the same line.
>
> In the linked video, the best solution using only $4$ moves is shown.
>   
>  There is also a $5$ move solution shown in the video, which would
>   apply to a restricted variant that includes:
>
> - Upon releasing the coins, at least one of the held coins must be touching one other coin.

## Follow Up Problem

I want to know if there exist solutions for $2n+1$ coins or not, and if there is a best generalized method to reach them in least moves.

(Both for the standard set of rules and the restricted variation)

The solution for $n=1$ is trivial: we have $\text{OoO}$ where $1$ move solves to $\text{OOo}$ and holds for both variations.

The solutions for $n=2$ are shown in the video.
 ( $4$ and $5$ moves )

For $n=3$ we have: $\text{OoOoOoO}$ , where I found a solution in $11$ moves for standard set of rules, and one in $15$ moves for a restricted variation.

The solutions for $n\ge4$ are yet to be found or proven impossible.

 (I believe that all $n$ have a valid solution following a similar pattern)

---

In the video, they reference the case they are showing as "11 cent puzzle", since they are using dimes and cents, thus you are always moving 11 cents per move.

## Solution update

I have found a general solution that solves it in $n^2$ moves, and in $\frac{n(3n-1)}{2}$ moves for the restricted variation.

This is better than my previous solutions for $n=3$, and I believe the optimal method.

It wasn't actually that complicated. I will post it if no one is able to solve it ( or at least find a general solution of their own ).

Comment: It likely isn't 11 cents as there's no way to add 2x+3y to get 11 in a system where the choices for x,y are 1, 5, 10, 25.

Comment: @IanMacDonald You didn't even watch the video. 11 cents come from the fact that you are moving 11 cents at a time. 10+1 is 11

Comment: Is the final state allowed to have gaps between coins? E.g. OOxOOxooo, where 'x' is a gap.

Comment: @Lawrence No gaps in the final solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a general solution for the standard version.

> It is easiest to do it in reverse, starting at the end, because then there are not so many movable pairs. I'll denote the two coin types by X and O. The solution works by reversing an XOXOXO sequence to an OXOXOX sequence by pasting it next to a loose O and then removing the other end, i.e. O+XOXOXO = OXOXOX+O. With this trick as a building block, you can turn a separated sequence OOOOXXXX of even length to an alternating sequence OXOXOXOX from the inside out by reversing successively larger strings of alternating coins.
>
> ```
>  ................................OOOOOOXXXXX..
>  ..............................OXOOOOO..XXXX..
>  ..............................O..OOOOXOXXXX..
>  ..........................OXOXO..OOO....XXX..
>  ..........................O......OOOXOXOXXX..
>  ....................OXOXOXO......OO......XX..
>  ....................O............OOXOXOXOXX..
>  ............OXOXOXOXO............O........X..
>  ............O....................OXOXOXOXOX..
>  ..OXOXOXOXOXO................................
> ```
>
> This solution takes $n^2$ moves: The first reversal takes $1+1$ moves, the second $2+2$ moves, ... the last reversal takes $2(n-1)$ moves, and after that we need a final $n$ moves to join up the loose O with the alternating sequence of length $2n$. The solution therefore takes $1+2+3+...+(n-1)+n+(n-1)+...+3+2+1 = n^2$ moves.

Here is a general solution for the restricted rule set.

> In the normal solution, it all works except for the first $n$ moves. These are the moves that go to here:
>
> ```
>  ............O....................OXOXOXOXOX..
> ```
>
> from here:
>
> ```
>  ..OXOXOXOXOXO................................
> ```
>
> These $n$ moves need to be replaced by a set of $n(n+1)/2$ moves, each of which simply moves the leftmost OX and appends it at the right-hand side. This gives a restricted solution of $n(n+1)/2 + n^2 - n = n(3n-1)/2$ moves.